# Storing nested Json in parse.com classes

Tags: json, class, object, parse-platform

I'm setting up my data structure for my first parse.com app. I am from a relational data background, so I'm not sure what I can and can't do when storing data in parse.
So my question is, can I store the Json below in a parse class as one object or would I have to split it into multiple classes / objects for the "fixtures" and "location" fields?

```
{
  "name": "fast five",
  "rules": "round robin",
  "location": [
  {
    "long":"18.633456",
    "lat":"-33.880178", 
    "venue":"Velodrome, Cape Town", 
    "date_time":"2011-08-21T18:02:52.249Z"
    }
  ],
  "teams": [
    "gauteng west",
    "gauteng north"
  ],
  "fixtures": [
  {
    "teamA":"gauteng west",
    "teamB":"gauteng west", 
    "court":"court 5", 
    "date_time":"2011-08-21T18:02:52.249Z"
    },
    {
    "teamA":"gauteng west",
    "teamB":"gauteng west", 
    "court":"court 5", 
    "date_time":"2011-08-21T18:02:52.249Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse supports storing JSON in a column on a Parse Object, but you won't be able to query based on values inside that.  It's tough to quickly sketch out the perfect schema for using more of Parse Data, but it could be something like this:

```
Location class
-venue   : "Velodrome, Cape Town"
-date    : a date object 
-location: a Parse GeoPoint object with that lat/lon

Team class:
-name: "gauteng west"

Fixture class:
-teamA   : a Team class object
-teamB   : a Team class object
-location: a Location class object
-court   : "court 5"
-date    : a date object 

Event class
-name    : "fast five"
-rules   : "round robin"
-teams   : an array of Team class objects
-location: a Location class object 
-fixtures: an array of Fixture class objects
```

With this separation, you could get all the data for an event at once:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Event");
query.include(['teams', 'fixtures', 'location']);
query.first().then(function(event) {
  var teams = event.get('teams');
  console.log(teams[0].get('name'));
});
```

Or query for events near a given location:

```
var locQuery = new Parse.Query("Location");
locQuery.near("location", a Parse GeoPoint object);
var query = new Parse.Query("Event");
query.matchesQuery("location", locQuery);
query.find().then(function(results) {
  // has all events sorted by distance from provided geopoint
}, function(err) {
  // error
});
```

And many other benefits..

Comment: Ok, so I still normalize my data structure, just without the join tables and foreign keys?

Comment: Right.. The foreign key / join table concepts would be handled for you if you save a parse object (or an array of parse objects) on to another object.  There's also the concept of relation tables, which is all in the docs.